# Pick color from screen in PhpStorm color picker

Tags: css, phpstorm

I want to pick a color on screen in PhpStorm with color picker. Is there any option is available on PhpStorm to pick color on screen? I need this tool for making CSS color schemes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click the palette icon ([image]) next to the current color:
[image]

Then you can pick a color from your screen

Answer (score 1):

Per this tutorial: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/changing-color-values-in-style-sheets.html

1. Open the desired style sheet for editing.
2. Type `color:`, and then press Ctrl+Space.
3. Select the desired color value from the suggestion list, or choose color... to pick a custom one.

---

Personally I prefer to use this site: http://www.colorhexa.com/

It gives a lot of handy tools for generating a scheme and not just picking a colour straight out

Comment: @user1882503 Check out the much cooler http://colorschemedesigner.com/. By the way, why do you accept the answer, even if it does not answer your actual question? (Which my answer does)